# ouputs in semantic segmentation task

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

Im working on the Kaggle semantic segmentation task,

In the testing part of my code,

```
model = model.eval()
predictions =[]
for data in testdataloader:
    data = t.autograd.Variable(data, volatile=True).cuda()
    output = model.forward(data)
    _,preds = t.max(output, 1, keepdim = True)
```

when i do the preds part,the array is only filled with ,i was hoping it to be an array of maximum locations im not sure what is going wrong.
The `output` part works well,I have attached a screenshot for visualization of `output`[image]

Any sugestions on what is going wrong would be really helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is of the form `MiniBatch x Dim` what you are doing now is looking at which minibatch has the highest value. If you are testing it with a single sample (`MB = 1`) then you will always get `0` as your answer. Thus, you might want to try:

```
_,preds = t.max(output, 0, keepdim = False)
```